# Booting from Ubuntu ISO CD - Windows 7 partitioning

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, disk

Do I partition Windows 7 hard disk before I install Ubuntu using disk utility in Windows 7?
Or do I do it with my Ubuntu ISO CD after booting?
And can I choose the size of the partition using Ubuntu ISO CD?

Comment: Let Ubuntu resize it after booting with the Ubuntu CD or DVD. It does that effectively and painlessly.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I partition windows 7 hard disk before I install Ubuntu using disk utility in windows 7.

Yes, you can do this.

> Or do I do it with my Ubuntu ISO CD after booting. And can I choose the size of the partition using Ubuntu ISO CD.

Yes, you can do this too.

The only difference is that, in the second case, you will find a ready-to-use empty partition to host Ubuntu, when you will be in the Ubuntu live session.

In any case, a defrag pass is recommended (from win7) to prepare the empty space you're planning to use for your Ubuntu partition. Faster and with the same result (for this scope) is to just "consolidate" the free space.

I also suggest to have a separated partition for your `/home` dir, as this can easily survive (and then conserve almost all your personal settings) from one Ubuntu version to the next one. It's also easier to backup.